# What is the point of a pure-virtual member function with function body?

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

I just learned to my amazement that the following is legal C++

```
struct A {
  void foo(int) const = 0;  // pure virtual
  // ...
};
void A::foo(int) const { /* ... */ }
```

What are sensible use cases for this? I.e. when would `A::foo` ever be called and why is this the correct/best implementation? Are there any differences here between C++03 and C++11?

---

Okay, there was a previous question (which I didn't find) with the same intention. However that was pre C++11. So my last question remains valid.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that previous question. My search didn't bring it up. However, that question was pre C++11. So the last part of my question remains unanswered.

Comment: Just for confirmation "void foo(int) const = 0;" Is this a valid way for declaring pure virtual function, even without virtual keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are sensible use cases for this?

If the function has a sensible default implementation, or a partial implementation of whatever is relevant to the base class, but you still want to force derived classes to override it, that's a good place to put it.

Also, as noted in the comments, you might want to force a class with no pure virtual functions to be abstract. You can do this by making the destructor pure virtual; but the destructor must have a body, whether or not it's pure virtual.

> when would `A::foo` ever be called?

It can only be called non-virtually; for example:

```
struct B : A {
    void f(int i) const {
        A::foo(i);    // non-virtual call
        // Do the B-specific stuff
    }
};
```

> why is this the correct/best implementation?

The alternative would be to invent a new name for the partial/default implementation, in addition to an unimplemented pure virtual function.

> Are there any differences here between C++03 and C++11?

No.

Comment: +1, I would also add that the common use case is a pure virtual destructor which is used sometimes to force creating derived types but that it must have a definition as the derived type must call the base destructor.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Good point, I've added a note about that.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical use-case is to mark a class as abstract by providing a pure-virtual destructor - which MUST have an implementation.

It's been the rule since before C++98.

Comment: Um - "an implementation" == "with a body", no?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: He is not talking about *any* function, but the *destructor* that **must** be defined.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is legal.
**Pure virtual functions are meant** that instance of that class in which it declared can`t be instantiated, not that it can`t has an implementation.
It`s like interface in C#, for example.

What opportunities it provides?
1. client can use **default implementation**.
2. classes with **pure virtual destructor** no longer raise **linker error**
(when you apply delete to pointer to base class: destructors of derived class are invoked, and after that destructor of base class is invoked, if you ommit implementation - linker will raise an error).

**References:** need for implementation in pure virtual method is described in depth in the book "Effective C++" by Scott Myers